# How to always show the horizontal scroll bar in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is it possible to *always* show the horizontal scroll bar in an [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)? This question was asked as [an issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/783), but they seem to have ignored it (best I can tell, it was not created in [their own issue tracker](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/)).

I'm open to official solutions, CSS hacks, anything that works really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**2022 Update**

```typescript
const gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    alwaysShowHorizontalScroll: true
}
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-options/#reference-scrolling-alwaysShowHorizontalScroll

Comment: This would not work for mac users that by default have their scroll bar not set to visible always in the OS settings... in that case you have to do CSS manipulation to show the native scrollbar... in my case it solved my problem...

Comment: i love ag griddd

Answer (score 10):

Solution that also covers macOS/WwebKit browsers

```
.ag-body-viewport-wrapper.ag-layout-normal {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

You also need to set property 'scrollbarWidth' on ag-Grid to the width/height number value above

```
scrollbarWidth=8
```

This way when you have more rows than fits on the screen, the last row will not be obscured by the scrollbar. This can happen when you have a summary row in ag-Grid.

Working Plunker [demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/FCgOocDM1ALJXPXd).

Thanks @Parotish for providing the base plunker demo that I modified.

Comment: Hey, thank you! Quick thing: the scrollbar does show, but then goes away after the grid does the row vertical resizing (via `setTimeout(() => {
            this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
        }, 500);` that I call in my `onGridReady` callback. Any idea what to do about that?

Comment: One other thing: your example always shows the vertical scroll bar as well. Even removing `overflow-y: scroll;` it is still there. Is there a way to remove that to only show the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: omg I've been trying to get the scrollbar to show since yesterday - but for a frozen column its very tricky I found it impossible to get it to show. Today I tried a new search and found this - it works so neatly - thanks a ton! Google may have a lot of answers, but we have to ask the right question :)

Answer (score 5):

You could set it by CSS

```
.ag-body-viewport-wrapper.ag-layout-normal {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

For live example, refer to this [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/3XICIC3Fs6gLRUnqpynU?p=preview)

Try removing columns from column-menu and you'll see that scrollbar is getting displayed anyways.

Comment: You get the stamp of approval from ag-grid ;)

Comment: LOL! Why to make things complicated if it can be simply achieved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see the horizontal scroll bar when I load the Plunk in either Chrome or Safari. I had manually played around with trying to set `overflow-x: scroll` on every div in my DOM that was around the rows, and none of it seemed to work. To be clear: I want the scrollbar to show even when the user is not scrolling.

Comment: Did u check the plunk i provided? I created that for chrome. Latest version till date. Provide screenshot or gif or elaborate.

Comment: I'm on Chrome v70 on Mac https://ibb.co/c9fnvf and Safari v12 https://ibb.co/grt7vf. This doesn't work on either (see images).

Comment: the plunk didn't load... seems to be stuck at
"Loading ag-Grid example…"
Giving some errors on the console... (failed to load resource shim) am already busy debugging my own app :) so didn't go too much into more details