# How to add a horizontal scrollbar on top of the ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid set up with a series of components in place for cell rendering.  When my dataset loads the vertical scroll works well but the horizontal scroll isn't obvious unless using a trackpad or horizontal scroll enabled mouse.

I would like to be able to add a scroll bar to the top of the grid as well as the automatically generated one at the bottom?

Has anyone encountered this, come up with as solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to always show the horizontal scroll bar in ag-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767610/how-to-always-show-the-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-ag-grid)

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but I struggled with the same issue and came up with something working.

#### The Idea

The main idea behind my solution is to...

- clone AgGrid scrollbar when grid is ready
- insert the cloned scrollbar on top of the grid
- add event listeners on both scrollbars to keep the scroll position synchronized
- use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to observe `style` attribute changes on original AgGrid scrollbar element (and child) to keep the size of the cloned scrollbar synchronized

#### ⚡ The Code

> The following code is for Angular but the concept is the same for Vanilla JS, React or Vue.

First, get a hook on `gridReady` event:

```html
<ag-grid-angular
  ...
  (gridReady)="onGridReady()">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In the function associated to the event use the following code to clone the AgGrid scrollbar and keep the scrollbars synchronized:

```js
// hold the `MutationObserver` to be disconnected when component is destroyed
private mutationObserver: MutationObserver;

onGridReady() {
  // css class selectors
  const headerSelector = '.ag-header';
  const scrollSelector = '.ag-body-horizontal-scroll';
  const scrollViewportSelector = '.ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport';
  const scrollContainerSelector = '.ag-body-horizontal-scroll-container';

  // get scrollbar elements
  const scrollElement = document.querySelector(scrollSelector);
  const scrollViewportElement = document.querySelector(scrollViewportSelector);
  const scrollContainerElement = document.querySelector(scrollContainerSelector);

  // create scrollbar clones
  const cloneElement = scrollElement.cloneNode(true) as Element;
  const cloneViewportElement = cloneElement.querySelector(scrollViewportSelector);
  const cloneContainerElement = cloneElement.querySelector(scrollContainerSelector);

  // insert scrollbar clone
  const headerElement = document.querySelector(headerSelector);
  headerElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', cloneElement);

  // add event listeners to keep scroll position synchronized
  scrollViewportElement.addEventListener('scroll', () => cloneViewportElement.scrollTo({ left: scrollViewportElement.scrollLeft }));
  cloneViewportElement.addEventListener('scroll', () => scrollViewportElement.scrollTo({ left: cloneViewportElement.scrollLeft }));

  // create a mutation observer to keep scroll size synchronized
  this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutationList => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
      switch (mutation.target) {
        case scrollElement:
          cloneElement.setAttribute('style', scrollElement.getAttribute('style'));
          break;
        case scrollViewportElement:
          cloneViewportElement.setAttribute('style', scrollViewportElement.getAttribute('style'));
          break;
        case scrollContainerElement:
          cloneContainerElement.setAttribute('style', scrollContainerElement.getAttribute('style'));
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  // start observing the scroll elements for `style` attribute changes
  this.mutationObserver.observe(scrollElement, { attributeFilter: ['style'], subtree: true });
}
```

When destroying the component, disconnect the `MutationObserver` to avoid memory leaks.

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
  // stop observing
  this.mutationObserver.disconnect();
}
```

It's tricky and all based on keeping the cloned scrollbar synchronized with the original scrollbar but so far it works great for my use cases.

Good luck

Comment: For Angular users, you can put the code in a directive and use `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook instead of `gridReady` event to reuse the behavior easily on every grid!

Comment: Thanks, it mostly works, just seems to have a problem with pinned columns on the left.

Comment: I added code to find the element ag-horizontal-left-spacer and then clone it and set the style as your code shows and it works correctly with pinned columns.

Answer (score 1):

### **Update 2022**

```
::ng-deep{
 .ag-root-wrapper{
  .ag-root-wrapper-body{
    .ag-root{
      .ag-body-horizontal-scroll{
        order: 1;
      }
      .ag-header{
        order: 2;
      }
      .ag-floating-top{
        order: 3;
      }
      .ag-body-viewport{
        order: 4;
      }
      .ag-floating-bottom{
        order: 5;
      }
      .ag-overlay{
        order: 6;
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```