# How can I show horizontal scrollbar on top and bottom of grid in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid-react

I have an ag-grid-react set up with a series of components in place for cell rendering. When my dataset loads the vertical scroll works well but the horizontal scroll isn't obvious unless using a trackpad or horizontal scroll enabled mouse.

I would like to be able to add a scroll bar to the top of the grid as well as the automatically generated one at the bottom?

Has anyone encountered this, come up with as solution?

Thanks in advance.

Note :  I found this solution [How to add a horizontal scrollbar on top of the ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043625/how-to-add-a-horizontal-scrollbar-on-top-of-the-ag-grid) but seems this is old and not working.